# Java. Spring. Многопользовательский режим

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Подскажите, что прочитать, чтоб понять как Spring работает в многопользовательском режиме?

В частности, есть у меня Spring-MVC web-приложение. У него куча разных бинов, все они взаимодействуют друг с другом.

Есть бин (пусть будет - ConnectApi), который отвечает за подключение к удаленному серверу по API.

Теперь представим, что залогинились через Spring-security два пользователя И каждый из них хочет подключиться к одному и тому же удаленному серверу по API через бин ConnectApi.

Мне нужно самостоятельно описать , что для каждой сессии создавать свой экземпляр бина или спринг сам не дурак?

Comment: Бин, если не меняли скоуп, ConnectApi будет один на все приложение. На счет подключения, я думаю надо явно подключатся. Спринг об этом не знает, да и наверно не должен знать ибо это уже относится к конкретному функционалу.

Посмотрите еще в сторону слушателей разных. Может чего найдете. Еще фильтры Spring Security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию Spring все бины создаёт в скоупе singleton - то есть, один экземпляр на приложение. Для веб-приложений можно заставить Spring создавать новый экземпляр бина на каждую сессию или запрос. Сделать это можно, пометив бин аннотацией [`@Scope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html) со значением `"session"` или `"request"` соответственно. Если используется Spring Boot, то можно использовать аннотации `@SessionScope` и `@RequestScope`, которые являются сокращёнными версиями `@Scope("session")` и `@Scope("request")` соответственно. Если используется XML-конфиг, то нужно к описанию бина добавить параметр `scope`:

```
<bean id="userPreferences" class="com.foo.UserPreferences" scope="session"/>
```

[Подробнее о скоупах бинов](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes)